# jq Split value on base space and join to one string

Tags: jq

I would like to ask for help. I need to split values from key "Text" on base space " " and join to one line. In actually code I calculate with exactly position but if key Text has S10 is show only S1.

My input

```
[   
    {
            "PartNumber": "5SE32DFVLG002",
            "ClassificationNo": "500001",
            "StringValue": "R0050SWSW",
            "Field": "95001",
            "Text": "S1 W1  cr.sec+colour"   
},   
    {
            "PartNumber": "5SE32DFVLG002",
            "ClassificationNo": "500001",
            "StringValue": "R0050SWSW",
            "Field": "95004",
            "Text": "S1 W10 cr.sec+colour"   
} 
]
```

My actually condition in jq play

> [.Oslm[] | select(.ClassificationNo=="500001" and .StringValue!="")  |
> {PartNumber,ClassificationNo,StringValue,Field,Text}] |
> sort_by(.Field) | .[] | [.PartNumber,.ClassificationNo,
> .Field[3:5],.Text[0:2] + "-" + .Text[3:5] + .StringValue[0:1], "Test
> ", .StringValue[1:10]] | join(";")

Actual result

```
5SE32DFVLG002;500001;95001;S1-W1R;TEST;0050SWSW 
5SE32DFVLG002;500001;95004;S1-W1R;TEST;0050SWSW
```

I would like to have this result

```
5SE32DFVLG002;500001;95001;S1-W1R;TEST;0050SWSW 
5SE32DFVLG002;500001;95004;S1-W10R;TEST;0050SWSW
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the part involving generation of `.Text` to something simpler using `split()` method in `jq` that can be used to split on a single white-space. This way, you are not reliant on the length of the sub-fields you want to extract

```
( .Text | split(" ") | .[0] + "-" + .[1] ) + .StringValue[0:1]
```

i.e. with full code

```
.[] | [ select( .ClassificationNo =="500001" and .StringValue != "" ) | 
{ 
  PartNumber, 
  ClassificationNo, 
  StringValue, 
  Field, 
  Text 
} ] |
sort_by(.Field) |
map(
  .PartNumber,
  .ClassificationNo, 
  .Field[3:5], 
  ( .Text | split(" ") | .[0] + "-" + .[1] ) + .StringValue[0:1], 
  "Test", .StringValue[1:10]
) | 
join(";")
```

demo at [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/McosnjNEhlu)

Comment: Can you please include the full code in the answer? We have a countless number of expired jqplay links on stackoverflow. They are not really helpful in the long run.